# Screen share between OS X and iOS

Tags: macos, ios, software-recommendation, screen-sharing

Anyone knows any application that will allow me to share my OS X Lion screen with an iPhone? I don't care to have it over the Internet, WiFi is sufficient.

Comment: There are dozens and dozens of apps that do this; try just doing a search for "screen sharing" in the App Store.

Comment: The big division line is some apps mirror the Lion screen using VNC screen sharing and others allow the iPad to be an additional virtual screen. Are you looking for one, the other or both?

Comment: I am just looking to share the screen of the Lion to an iPhone. I don't care for giving control to the iPhone. It may as well work only on local WifI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been using [Remoter VNC](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/remoter-remote-desktop-vnc/id369626098?mt=8) for a while now and I'm quite happy with the result. [Their website](http://rafsoftware.com/rafsoftware/home/) covers most of it's features, so I suggest you take a look and find out yourself if it fits your needs.

[image]

Comment: Seems good but its gonna cost like £13 and has way more stuff than I need on it.

Comment: I don't know which app you've clicked on, but VNC will cost you only about $1.99.

Comment: @latusaki +1 Remoter VNC is great. If you want something free [Mocha VNC Lite](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mocha-vnc-lite/id284984448?mt=8) should do the job and is designed for both iPhone and iPad.

Answer (score 3):

The title of the question says iOS, so here's an iPad solution.

I use [DisplayPad](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/displaypad/id399786470?mt=8) (currently $2.99 USD). It's great because it's got close to zero configuration parameters: it just works. My Mac treats the iPad like a second monitor.

It doesn't work on the iPhone as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the free app VNC Viewer by RealVNC, available on iOS, OS X, and Windows. The app is barebones and the icon looks from the 80s but it works perfectly, simply, fast, and, it's free.

I don't recommend TeamViewer, it requires you to run another piece of software at all times on the sharing computer, and can cause heavy resource usage on that computer, in addition to causing other major bugs (it did for me anyway). The only good thing about it is that it can share audio, which VNC does not do.

Just open the app, create a new profile, and put in your mac's IP address. (Also, you must enable screen sharing in the mac system preferences/sharing if it's not already.)

You can also access remotely if you forward the VNC port (5900) to your mac in router, and signup for a dynamic dns service (free to set up with some routers), this can be very useful sometimes.

Comment: This is the best free solution, should be the accepted answer. Note the RealVNC connection to screenshare is not secure (and creds are sent without encryption). Relevant followup: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/136883/is-there-an-actually-secure-vnc-ios-app-for-use-with-os-x-screen-sharing

Answer (score 0):

Teamviewer app works great. You just register a user name and password, add a device via a code from the teamviewer app you installed on it, and voila, it works. I have this on most of my gadgets, and each one can see the others.. well, the mobile apps can interact with the PCs/servers/laptops and so forth.

Oh, and it's free for home use, works over wifi or internet/remotely, with no need for port forwarding or anything.