# Is It Possible To Use Desktop Mac Apps On An iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, software-recommendation, screen-sharing

Wouldn't it be cool, if you could somehow use the desktop software running on your Mac on your iPad !!!

Is this possible ?

Comment: @Downvoter Any particular reason for the downvote ?

Comment: Same question. It's a reasonable inquiry, given how often people are using iPads now in lieu of laptops and desktops.

Comment: @Dave If it is viable, I think its a perfectly reasonable question like you say in your comments above, iPad usage must be sky high, and if there are solutions to use Desktop Software on them... Whoopee!

Comment: If you're only looking for screen sharing, we have several leads already on the site: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50081/screen-share-between-os-x-and-ios and searching the [tag:screen-sharing] should help.

Comment: @bmike Appreciate the additional info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using remote desktop tools, yes.

For example, [Remoter VNC](http://remoterlabs.com/main/), [LogMeIn](https://secure.logmein.com), and [Teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx) come to mind immediately.

Comment: I have decided to accept your answer as the correct answer, as Parallels Access is only in its infancy at present.

Answer (score 4):

[Parallels Access](http://www.parallels.com/products/access/), a new iPad App from [Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/) makes it easier to use desktop software on your Apple iPad tablet. With one part remote access and one part native iPad app, you get a desktop experience on a tablet that almost feels like you are using the software just like it was on your Mac.

For more info see the link above and also read this [review](http://www.macobserver.com/tmo/review/run-any-mac-or-pc-app-remotely-on-your-ipad-with-parallels-access) published in The Mac Observer yesterday.

Additionally see this [introductory video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qqd_TT67r3c).

It is a premium product $80 per year, however a 14 day free trial is available (Windows/OS X/iPad Compatible).

Comment: I just got an email about that product this morning. They lost me on the $79/year subscription fee, especially when there are cheaper (as in, no annual fee) alternatives. (I'm glad you pointed it out here though as an option for the OP.)

Comment: @Dave This is it, for some people the price will be a concern. For avid Parallel fans though, Christmas has come early (I suspect).

Comment: I also recommend the Parallels Remote Desktop app, which allows you to connect to your Parallels VMs. I do grant that they produce very robust, functional apps.

Comment: @Dave I'm sure their brand name will carry them a long way.

Comment: I just test drove Parallels Access. It definitely adds a bit of "appification" to the desktop experience. I can see this being a boon for sales and marketing types. I'm not sure it adds much to the support and IT side of things, as RDP/VNC tools accomplish much of that. But to take a Windows machine and make it instantly into a draggable desktop UI is a great win for Parallels. Now, if they had 1) multiple users per agent, and 2) a corporate bulk rate, that would make it sellable in my company.

Comment: @Dave Thanks very much for test driving much appreciated. I wanted to ask you - which answer should I tick as the correct one ? This has only just come onto the market, is expensive, is however from a reputable company (surely will have updates in the future) Vs the freemium alternatives you gave in your answer.....Unless of course there are more answers given.

Comment: The operative phrase is "use the desktop software running on your Mac on your iPad". To me, both responses are worth consideration. The question didn't specify anything about look-and-feel, or about cost of solution. Those caveats would guide one toward one answer or the other. Both probably deserve upvotes, to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

As other users suggested, this may be possible using other "middleman" software.

However, all (relatively new) Macs have Intel CPUs and all iOS iPhone/Pod/Pads have ARM processors. The compiled binary files are simply not compatible.

Remember that, although they share components, these are fundamentally different OSs. OS X  (mostly) uses the AppKit Framework for UI, and iOS uses the UIKit Framework. Although these APIs are very similar, they are not interchangeable.

So, even if there was a way to trick your iOS device into accepting a *.app file, it would never launch (or crash immediately upon launching) without fundamental changes to the hardware and software architecture of iOS and its devices.

Answer (score 0):

There are several dozen VNC and RDP apps in the iOS App Store (and yes, there seem to be at least 2 vendors of RDP servers for the Mac), as well as another few that use custom remote display viewing protocols, that allow one to use software running on your Mac on your desk from an iPad while sitting on your couch (etc.).

Many of these apps have been available since before the first iPad was announced, and run on the iPhone as well.